# Illegal reflective access on Streams using reflection

Tags: java, reflection, illegalaccessexception

I'm using reflection to invoke methods on java.util.stream.Stream but because the actual implementations (ReferencePipeline etc.) have the actual code which runs, I get illegal reflective access warnings when calling `method.setAccessible(true)`, and without that call, it doesn't work. I was wondering whether there is a way to automatically delegate this to a super method where access isn't illegal? That is, I want to call `filter` where it's legal on `java.util.stream.Stream` and not `ReferencePipeline` or whatever the implementation is.

EDIT Here is some code. `target` is a concrete instance of a Stream obtained via reflection.

```
assert target instanceof java.util.stream.Stream;

Method candidate = Stream.of(target.getClass().getMethods())
    .filter(method -> method.getName().equals("filter"))
    //.filter(myComplicatedCriteria) - omitted for brevity
    .findAny().orElseThrow();

try {
    candidate.setAccessible(true);
    return candidate.invoke(target, candidateParameterValues);
}
catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException ex) {
    throw new EolRuntimeException(ex);
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide code to illustrate the problem?

Comment: A minimal example would require too much code since it's reflection. The problem is that I'm invoking what is supposedly a perfectly legal method (e.g. `filter`) but because the instance it's being invoked on is a subclass of Stream there's no way to convince Java that I'm trying to use the "legal" one

Comment: An overriden method can't limit the visibility of a super method. You are most likely trying to access an overloaded method in a child class. There is no way to tell what's happening since you don't want to provide the code :(

Comment: Surely there must be something that can be done with `MethodHandles`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the interface class `Stream` instead of the implementing class `target.getClass()`. Change the code to:

```
Method candidate = Stream.of(Stream.class.getMethods())
        .filter(method -> method.getName().equals("filter"))
        ...
```

Root cause of the problem is `java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline` as well as `java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.Head` being package protected. Your class can't access these classes using reflection even if the `filter()` method itself is defined as `public`.

The `Stream.class.getMethods()` approach will work because your class can access the public `Stream` class. See `sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess()` check if you need details.